# Edit List View Not appearing for Sys Admin Profile User

Tags: custom-object, list-view, system-admin

I have created a custom Object and I have a System Administrator Profile . I am not able to see Edit View for All. I have Manage Public List View Permission for the System Admin
[image]

Surprisingly for other objects I am able to see it. Can anyone tell me where I can check this to make it visible.

Comment: do you have tab for this object?

Comment: Yes I do. When I click on it the recent list comes up as usual.

Answer (score 2):

If you delete the last list view on an object, then a special "All" default list view will appear that cannot be edited or deleted. If you later add a new list view, this default view will disappear.

[image: Default All List View]

[image: One Custom List View]

Comment: Best answer @sfdcfox

Comment: In event object, permissions, view all and modify all is not available ,how to enable this permission for that event object @Sfdcfox